# How to rename a variable in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a variable defined as :

```
proxy_port : 3000
```

in my inventory file.

However, in my task.yml, I want to rename it as :

```
nodejs_proxy_port : "{{ proxy_port }}"
```

Is there a module to to the same?
I have tried using debug, but it does not allow to register a variable.

Comment: I'd just throw `nodejs_proxy_port : "{{ proxy_port }}"` in the `vars:` portion of your playbook.

Comment: vars portion of the playbook is available before the tasks are executed, I need this feature, after the playbook has started it's execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a *module* to set/modify a variable, then it is [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html)!

Example in your `task.yml`:

```yaml
tasks:
- name: set nodejs proxy port to proxy_port
  set_fact:
    nodejs_proxy_port: '{{ proxy_port }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Two way cross my mind.

The most obvious one is to use the [`set_fact` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html).

```yaml
- name: Set nodejs_proxy_port to proxy_port
  set_fact:
    nodejs_proxy_port: "{{ proxy_port }}"

- name: This is a task where I use my new nodejs_proxy_port var
  debug:
    msg: "my nodejs port is {{ nodejs_proxy_port }}"
```

But I found writing a complete task just to set a variable a bit heavy.

So a second idea could be to use [task's var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) like this:

```yaml
- name: This is a task where I use my new nodejs_proxy_port var
  debug:
    msg: "my nodejs port is {{ nodejs_proxy_port }}"
  vars:
    nodejs_proxy_port: "{{ proxy_port }}"
```

And in the case your task is define in a role, you can declare your `nodejs_proxy_port: "{{ proxy_port }}"` into the [role's defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-default-variables) or role's vars.