# How to rename variables in an Ansible project?

Tags: variables, ansible, rename

I'm working on an Ansible repository with multiple hostfiles, playbooks and roles and want to introduce a general naming convention. This involves renaming a lot of variables that are used in multiple files.

Some of the variables are named the same, so I don't want to use find and replace.

Is there a better way to rename Ansible variables within their scope, like for programming languages?

I already searched for tools, VS code plugins etc. but wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: "_I want to introduce a general naming convention._", this is a very good idea. "_rename Ansible variables within their scope, like for programming languages?_" not I am aware of. "_I don't want to use find and replace._" I am afraid you have to and if you are not going to add more "code" and complexity into what is already there. See in example [How to rename a variable in Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898510/6771046)

Comment: If you can use IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm, you might want to check out [OrchidE](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12626-orchide--ansible-language-support) plugin, but it's paid. Personally I didn't try though - I'm fine with IDEA built-in find/replace functionality that can use directory-level scoping, and free [Ansible](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14893-ansible) plugin that provides some code completion and navigation features.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I also thought about directory level renaming for roles, but then there are still other variables like host_vars which could be used "anywere" in the repository